# Managing multiple locks

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the following situation: I'm concurrently processing requests that have a given key. I can process any number of requests at the same time, as long as each key in progress is unique.

I am a total rookie with concurrency in Java. There must be some pattern/utility/existing question for this, but I can't figure out what to search for. Hoping somebody could point me in the right direction, or comment on what I have so far.

This class manages the locks:

```
class LockMap<K> {
    private Map<K, Object> locks = new HashMap<>();

    void acquireLock(K key) throws InterruptedException {
        Object lockObj;
        synchronized (locks) {
            lockObj = locks.get(key);

            if (lockObj == null) lockObj = new Object();

            locks.put(key, lockObj);
        }

        synchronized (lockObj) {
            lockObj.wait();
        }
    }

    void releaseLock(K key) {
        Object lockObj;
        synchronized (locks) {
            lockObj = locks.get(key);
            locks.remove(key);
        }

        if (lockObj != null) {
            synchronized (lockObj) {
                lockObj.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use the lock manager like this:

```
// lockMap is instance of LockMap shared across all threads
void doSomething(K key) {
    lockMap.acquireLock(key);
    try {
        // something
    } finally {
        lockMap.releaseLock(key);
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: I don't get it. Why exactly do you need Locks?

Comment: By the way, this http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601 is an excellent book for any java programmer to have on his (or her) bookshelf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

create a `ConcurrentHashMap<K,Semaphore>`

`ConcurrentMap<K, Semaphore> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();`

in your `doSomething()` method, use the `putIfAbsent()` method to of your map to add a semaphore with one permit to the map, only if the key does not exist in the map.

subsequently do a `get()` on the key to fetch the semaphore for that key, and then do your stuff. Release the semaphore when done.

```
void doSomething(K key) {
     myMap.putIfAbsent(key, new Semaphore(1));
     Semaphore s = myMap.get(myKey);
     s.aquire();
     try {
     // do stuff
     } finally {
       s.release();
     }
 }
```

The only real problem with this scheme is if your list of keys will grow indefinitely, I don't have a good race-condition-free strategy for removing the semaphore from the map. (But if you know you will reuse the same keys over and over, or the list will grow slowly, then maybe this is ok.)

Comment: Alright thanks man, I will give that a try. Slightly pedantic question: is it necessary for s.acquire() to be inside the try?

Comment: I have heard some very smart folks say that it does not, but I do not fully understand the logic. I would say that if it is not IN the try, it should at least be the last statement before the try. (The key requirement is that you don't want it to be possible to acquire, then throw an uncaught exception, and never release.) I always put it inside the try for that reason.

Comment: good luck. If I think of a good, race-free way to delete the semaphores from the map when nobody needs it, I'll update my answer. Right now the problem is gnawing at me, and I have a feeling if I can't figure it out, I'll be posting a question of my own.. :)

Comment: Interesting. My task involves a fairly small set of keys that will be processed often, so this should work just fine.

Comment: Your question motivated me to do some more reading and update my answer: the reason why it is NOT correct to acquire inside the `try{}` block is because the `acquire()` operation is interruptible. Thus, a thread might throw an `InterruptedException` while blocked waiting to acquire the permit, and still call `release()` in the `finally` block; this would cause a *second permit* to be erroneously added to that Semaphore, so that from that moment on, *two* threads could  `acquire()` a permit to work on a given key, breaking your mutual exclusion requirement. So, acquire *just* outside the `try`.

Comment: Why did you use a `Semaphore` and not a `ReentrantLock` ?

Comment: @jbx -- in the problem the OP described, I don't think the implementation of `do stuff` would ever call `doSomething` recursively, so it's not clear the reentrancy would buy you anything. (I deleted an older reply that I wrote while half awake because it was just wrong)

Comment: OK, was just wondering why `Semaphore` instead of a simpler lock, since it doesn't seem the value is going beyond 1. `ReentrantLock` is just the simplest form that behaves just like `synchronized` with the difference that it can span across scopes or overlap other `synchronized` scopes. (An even simpler approach would be to use just an Object, but maybe the methods offered by `Lock` are a bit more useful)

Answer (score 3):

Following solution does not locks LockMap and so is extremly parallel. It uses custom-made `Locks` to track the moment when they can be deleted, and handles concurrent deletion/creation.

```
class Lock {
    boolean busy=true; // locked state, a thread is working
    int waitCount=0; // number of waiting threads

        /** returns true if lock succeeded */
    synchronized boolean tryLock() throws InterruptedException {
        if (busy) {
            waitCount++; 
        } else if (waitCount==0){
                // such values mean that the lock is deleted
            return false;
        } else {
            busy=true;
            return true;
        }
        for (;;) {
            wait();
            if (!busy) {
                waitCount--;
                busy=true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

}

class LockMap<K> {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<K, Lock> locks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    void acquireLock(K key) throws InterruptedException {
        for (;;) {
            Lock lockObj = locks.get(key);
            if (lockObj==null) {
                Lock myLockObj = new Lock();
                lockObj=locks.putIfAbsent(key, myLockObj);
                if (lockObj==null) {
                    // successfully inserted, and so locked
                    return;
                }
            }
            // lockObj existed, lock it or wait in queue
            if (lockObj.tryLock()) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void releaseLock(K key) {
        Lock lockObj = locks.get(key);
        synchronized (lockObj) {
            lockObj.busy=false;
            if (lockObj.waitCount==0) {
                locks.remove(key);
            } else {
                lockObj.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very insightful, thank you for the answer. This is the better answer of the two, but I feel lame changing my accepted answer. I'll give you a few up-votes elsewhere.

Comment: Very nice! I knew someone would come up with a better solution than mine eventually. Certainly *not* simpler to understand, (took me a while to work through all the possibilities in my head and convince myself there were no races,) but very thorough, and without the problem of safely removing the locks from the map. Thank you!

Comment: How would you write tests, via junit or similar libraries, for this solution?