# Wait for one of many parallel thread to complete

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, synchronization

Here is a brief description of what is happening -

Execution scenario :

Search Request `-->` Check if data exist in cache for this request `-->` if exist in cache, get it from cache otherwise get it from DB and put data in cache

This work's fine for following scenario

---

Here is a scenario if requests are received *sequentially*

**First request**  Request `-->` check cache(*doesnt exist as this is first request*)  --> get from DB and put in cache

**Second request** Request `-->` check cache(*data exists as previous request already made the data available in cache*)

**Third request** Request `-->` check cache(*data still exists*)

**Fourth request** Request `-->` check cache(*data still exists*)

---

however it fail's if multiple threads request's the data at the same time.

Here is a scenario if request are received in parallel (*at the same time*)

**First request**  Request `-->` check cache(*doesnt exist as this is first request*)  --> get from DB and put in cache

**Second request** Request `-->` check cache(*doesnt exist as this is first request*)  --> get from DB and put in cache

**Third request** Request `-->` check cache(*doesnt exist as this is first request*)  --> get from DB and put in cache

**Fourth request** Request `-->` check cache(*doesnt exist as this is first request*)  --> get from DB and put in cache

---

You spotted the problem ? every thread is hitting the database.

I am not using any synchronized block as that will make it a sequential execution, right ?

How can i avoid this problem, so that only one thread hit the database and other's pick that data from cache (*specially in case of parallel execution*) ? is their any pattern already exist to solve such problems ?

i know i mixed threads with requests, but they are essentially the same thing.

And feel free to modify title of this question if it looks bad.

Comment: `synchronized` is a keyword to mark a specific block of code only useable by one thread at a time - the idea is not to make everything `synchronized` but the crucial parts.

Comment: You said _one thread at a time_ , that is exactly what i want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

The first thread which see the object does not exist in the cache, creates temporary object of special class (a kind of Future) and places it in hash table. Then starts DB query.

Subsequent threads see temporary object and do not query DB but stay in line waiting the result to appear.

The first thread gets the result from DB and notifies other threads.

The class of Temporary object can be created from scratch, or based on guava's SettableFuture, java8 CompletableFuture, or java5 FutureTask.

Appendix

To make sure only one of concurrent threads starts DB fetching, the whole cache should be locked while a thread tests the cache and inserts temporary object. As a result, threads that access different keys compete with each other. If the access rate is high and this causes performance degradation,  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286831/managing-multiple-locks/21339300#21339300) may help. It explains the cache can be tested in parallel way. For your task, the solution should be updated so that fetched data are put in the cache.

Comment: _"The first thread which see the object does not exist in the cache"_ No, All threads are first threads if they started at the same time.

Comment: This is a good start for a solution, but needs some fine tuning. After a cache miss, an atomic `putIfAbsent(promise)` must be performed on the cache and only the winning thread goes on with DB fetching.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik yes, and I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use double-checked locking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) to ensure only one thread writes to the cache and the others only use the cache for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This issue reminds me about the singleton pattern with lazy initialization. If no synchronization is done, first parallel threads can create several instances, breaking the pattern's objective.

You can get inspiration from the [Lazy Initialization holder class idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) which solves the problem for singletons.

As caching can be tricky and full of pitfalls, I would recommand using third party cache implementations. For example, [Guava cache](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) already handles concurrency issues and should be handy for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure about any similarity of your problem with lazy initialization. I think you problem can be solved with very simple solution. To make it parallel you can use ReadWriteLocks like:

```
private final ReentrantReadWriteLock readWriteLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private final Lock cacheReadLock  = readWriteLock.readLock();
private final Lock dbWriteLock = readWriteLock.writeLock();
```

When you update cache from DB use writelock(dbWriteLock) and when you just reading from cache use simple readlock (cacheReadLock). Hope it helps. 
Feel free to comment if you want me to add more code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Atomic Integer** [say counter] (initialized to zero) and pass the same to all worker (thread). 
Whomsoever thread reaches the code point just after the cache check and just before entering the db will get called something like this:

> ```
> /* some code for read from cache */
> /* if not found in cache , then  only */
> boolean goAhead = counter.compareAndSet(0,1);
> if(goAhead) {
>           /* some code to read from db */
>           /* some code to put into cache */
>         synchronized(counter) {
>               counter.notifyAll();
>         }
>
>  } else {
>        synchronized(counter) {
>               counter.wait();
>         }
>         /* read from cache */
>   }
> ```

Please ensure that this (wait and notify) code will only get called when the cache is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The other simple solution is to do something like double checked locking as we use to do it to create singleton design pattern. I know your concern that you want to avoid synchronized, but using something like double checked null lock will allow only one thread to go to synchronized and other will wait the task to finish.

```
if (fetchFromCache() == null) {
    synchronized(this) { // or any monitor lock of choice
          if(fetchFromCache == null) {
                  // code to call db and fill cache data
         }
     }
}
return fetchFromCache(); // this call will never be null
```

[Similar implementation is explained here](http://www.singletonjava.blogspot.com/2015/12/java-singleton-design-pattern-double.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10908740)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have modified answer accordingly